# How to xss without '=' and '>'?

Tags: javascript, html, xss

HTML code:

```
<html>
  <script>
    input = input.replace(/[=>]/g, '');
    document.write('<article>'+input+'</article>');
  </script>
</html>
```

The `input` in the code is what user inputs(arbitrarily string), and I'm trying to `alert(1)`.
As you see, '=' and '>' is disabled, so how could I achieve that?

Comment: What is `input` initially?

Comment: input is a arbitrarily string.

Comment: Sure, but you've not defined in it the code you've shown here, so it's not clear what is being replaced

Comment: woo~it's my fault...

Comment: Try to use `%3D` instead of `=` and `%3E` for `>` in your payload. In some cases it works.

Comment: @Rahman Could you please point it out what case it works? I tried your solution in [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8kL0nok0/), however, it failed.

Comment: @csharpfolk: But without `=`?

Comment: @Sayakiss take a look at this: http://www.technicalinfo.net/papers/CSS.html#table4

Answer (score 2):

A regex which only filters `=` OR `>` can be bypassed by e.g. `<script>alert(0);</script>` or `<img src=x onerror="javascript:alert(0)"<`. However, I am not aware of any bypass for your regex that removes both `=` and `>` from the input.

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like you are employing a hacky XSS-prevention strategy for no good reason.

If you are outputting a value as raw HTML, that would suggest you want to allow the user to be able to use HTML in their input. But it's hard to have any meaningful HTML without `=` and `>`.

If you only want to allow the user to enter plain text, then treat it properly and you should be fine:

```
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.textContent = input;
document.write('<article>' + div.innerHTML + '</article>');
```

And as Bergi points out below, if you are not limited to using `document.write()`, you are better off using DOM manipulation.

```
document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('article')).textContent = input;
```

Comment: OP might be *evaluating* an existing XSS-filter, not trying to come up with his own. Still good to know the correct solution!

Comment: If that's the case, then that existing XSS-filter is pretty awful. Even if it succeeds in preventing XSS, it results in text that has all the `=`s and `>`s removed.

Comment: Does your solution prevent all XSS attacks? And could you please explain a little bit about the magic behind your solution?

Comment: Why not just `document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('article')).textContent = input;`?

Comment: @Bergi Yes, that is absolutely what they should use when they can, but sometimes (veeeeery rarely), it seems there are times when people need to use `document.write()` for some valid reason, apparently.

Comment: @Sayakiss Yes, AFAIK it should prevent all attacks resulting from adding a user input to the page. The way it works is that it creates an element and adds the value to it as _text content_, then it retrieves the _HTML content_ of that element. Since the element contains only text, the result will be fully escaped and safe. For example, if `input` is `<script>alert(0);</script>` then the `div.innerHTML` in the third line would evaluate to `&lt;script&gt;alert(0);&lt;/script&gt;`.